# Parcelable implementation with ArrayList<custom-object>

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

I think it's just a stupid mistake but the `ArrayList` always ends up `null`. It's driving me crazy so thought I'd ask for help.

Object class:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class StoryTag implements Parcelable {

    private String tagTitle;
    private int occurrence;

    public StoryTag() {

    }

    public StoryTag(Parcel in) {
        tagTitle = in.readString();
        occurrence = in.readInt();
    }

    public String getTagTitle() {
        return tagTitle;
    }

    public void setTagTitle(String tagstring) {
        this.tagTitle = tagstring;
    }

    public int getOccurrence() {
        return occurrence;
    }

    public void setOccurrence(int occurrence) {
        this.occurrence = occurrence;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(tagTitle);
        dest.writeInt(occurrence);
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<StoryTag> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<StoryTag>() {

        public StoryTag createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new StoryTag(in);
        }

        public StoryTag[] newArray(int size) {
            return new StoryTag[size];
        }
    };
}
```

`MainActivity`:

```
Intent tagIntent=new Intent(this,DisplayTagList.class);
tagIntent.putExtra("taglist", taglist);
startActivity(tagIntent);
return true;
```

Receiving activity:

```
Bundle storyTagBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<StoryTag> listoftags = storyTagBundle.getParcelable("taglist");
```

Thanks a ton for any help you can offer. Pulling my hair out here for what I think is a minor error.

Comment: Follow this: http://andhradroid.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/how-to-pass-the-object-one-activity-from-another/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `putExtra()` and `getSerializable()` methods will store and retrieve an `ArrayList<?>` of your custom objects, with no interface implementing required. (Your custom object class should implement `Serializable` interface though).

But in your case, you can simply use [`putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29) and [`getParcelableArrayListExtra(String name)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Do not use Serializable!  Use putParcelableArrayListExtra()

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike - I've clearly mentioned, that in _OP_'s case, he should use `putParcelableArrayListExtra()`. The `Serializable` part was just a general usage thing.